# Put a value to a variable in Maple

Tags: maple

I have these commands and I would like to put a value 2.02682872387444 from table to a variable for example a. How can I do it?

> DR1 := diff(x(t), t) = 100*x(t)-3*x(t)*y(t)
>
> DR2 := diff(y(t), t) = -40*y(t)+x(t)*y(t)
>
> PP := x(0) = 150, y(0) = 100
>
> dsolve({DR1, DR2, PP}, {x(t), y(t)}, numeric, method = classical[foreuler], output = array([0, 0.5e-2, 0.1e-1, 0.15e-1, 0.2e-1, .25]), stepsize = 0.5e-3)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does `a:=2.02682872387444` do what you want? I can't tell what this number, or the variable named `a`, have to do with the code in your question.

Comment: [MaplePrimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com/) definitely is a better place for such questions.